# Integrating a tensorflow session in an wxPython application

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, wxpython

I'm new to xwPython, so sorry for the perhaps stupid question. I have checked online everywhere but can't find a way to integrate a tensorflow session into a wxPython application.

I need to start a `tf.Session` and restore a model. After this, I want to control the loading of new data, and running the neural net from the graphical interface of my xwApp.

How can I structure the program so that both `tf.Session` and the `wx.App().MainLoop()` run in parallel?